# JCache ACL Cache for Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-acl, jcache

I'm using Spring Security ACL and it needs to have cache defined. So far I was using this:

```
@Bean(name = { "defaultAclCache", "aclCache" })
protected AclCache defaultAclCache() {
    return new SpringCacheBasedAclCache(defaultAclJCacheFactory(), defaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(), defaultAclAuthorizationStrategy());
}
```

and it all worked fine. However, I switched to use `jcache` and now `defaultAclJCacheFactory()` returns an instance of `javax.cache.Cache` which is incompatible with the `SpringCacheBasedAclCache`:

```
@Bean(name = { "defaultAclJCacheFactory", "aclJCacheFactory" })
protected Cache defaultAclJCacheFactory() {
    return cacheManager.getCache("acl_cache");
}
```

I tried to search for a `JCache` implementation of `org.springframework.security.acls.model.AclCache` but there's only this one for spring cache and one for EhCache. Is there any plans to introduce one for `jcache`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `JCacheCacheManager` implementation to obtain an instance of `org.springframework.cache.Cache` For example:

```
@Bean(name = { "defaultAclCache", "aclCache" })
protected AclCache defaultAclCache(org.springframework.cache.CacheManager springCacheManager) {
    org.springframework.cache.Cache cache = 
        springCacheManager.getCache("acl_cache");
    return new SpringCacheBasedAclCache(cache, 
        defaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(), 
        defaultAclAuthorizationStrategy());
}

// Depending on your configuration, you may not even need this
@Bean
public JCacheCacheManager springCacheManager(javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager) {
    return new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
}
```

Comment: why "depending on your configuration...."

Comment: also why can't I find a canonical example of this in spring documentation or examples?